# Difficulty covering all page with background

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a navbar fixed on top.

I also have a background image which covers the entire page by using `position: absolute`.
This worked fine until I added more divs in the main page. When the divs exceed the window height, the background does not cover the bottom:

Here's the fiddle without too much divs: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2L21cnf/8/)

And here's one with 'too much' divs [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2L21cnf/10/)

When scrolling appears, the background does not cover the scroll-able area.
How do I cope with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `position:fixed` if you want the background to be on the same place while you scroll the rest of the page content.

Comment: No, I would like the background to move with the page

Comment: @DM Yes, but you want the background to be fixed in the background, like, the content is moving but your background is a still on the .... background?

Did you try using position fixed to see if that was the result you hoped for?

Comment: I don't the background to be fixed. I want it to move with content...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be feasible in a flex-based layout, and moving the background to the `.main` element.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/255379/pexels-photo-255379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size:cover;
}

.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin:10px auto;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>

<div class="main">

  <div class="box">
    Bla bla
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Bla bla
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Too much
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Too much
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This almost works. The problem now is that the background does not fill the whole page in the case where there are less divs..
There is a white bar on the bottom.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I missed some styles. Please retry.

Answer (score 0):

Add background-image to body style

```
body{
background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/255379/pexels-photo- 
255379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');

}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2L21cnf/21/)

Comment: I do not want to add the background to the body. Each page should have its own background.

Comment: @DM add a class to the body tag then?

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the height of your background, however, this will be distorted.
The background cannot move with the page as it set at a particular height and position.
Possibly rearrange the div's to fit the height.